# z/OS C/C++ fseeko is very slow for multi-volume data sets

Tags: java, c, mainframe, zos

The `fseeko` call takes many seconds on a multivolume data set, for example:

```
stream=fopen("//'A.B.C'", "rb,type=record");
fseeko(stream, 40000, 0);
```

It takes over 8 seconds. As noted in the comments, there are a number of APARs logged describing the issue:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PK5078
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PQ94363

The question is: is it possible to improve performance without moving to single volume or multi-striped data sets?

**The original question was:**

I have data set A.B.C with parameters `PO=PS` and `RECFM=FS`. The following Java code runs fast for a single-volume data set.

```
ZFile zfile = new ZFile("//'A.B.C'", "rb,type=record");
file.seek(1000);
file.seek(2000);
file.seek(4000);
```

Seek function takes a few milliseconds.

If the data set A.B.C is allocated on multiple volumes, each call `file.seek()` takes a few seconds. Further experiments showed that the access is actually sequential,  for example, call `zfile.seek(10000)` takes 10 times longer than call `zfile.seek(1000)`.

What is the proper way to do ZFile.seek for a multi-volume data set?

Comment: Offhand, I think this sounds like a bug, and a case should be opened.  A couple of questions: is this real hardware or zD&T/zPDT? Also, why RECFM=FS? I haven’t seen FS in serious decades.

Comment: Yes, it is real hardware and I agree that it sounds like a bug. It is an existing data set with RECFM=FS, I have no control over this.

Comment: The data set with RECFM=F has the same slow seek issue

Comment: I can remember some performance-problems with C/C++-appplications (and the JRE is one) and multivolume datasets, but that has been years ago. I did find an APAR mentioning somthing like this, but it is for z/OS 1.8 and has a fix since the end of 2007 (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PK50785). Which z/OS version are you running?

Comment: The issue was reproduced on both z/OS V2R2 and V2R3.

Comment: I'm getting some more information about this, but short version seems to be that this is known/expected behavior, due to the underlying C libraries.  If possible, it's suggested you move to a multi-volume striped dataset.

Comment: Kevin, thank you for the answer. I appreciate it if you can provide this additional information. Do you see any workaround without modifying the data set (moving to the multi-volume stripped data set)?  It does not belong to us, but rather to a customer.

Comment: I'm told another option might be using setPos and getPos instead of Seek, as those use faster C functions.

Comment: It is a little counter-intuitive, but you can only `setPos` and `getPos` if you use it to _return_ to a record you have been to. For example, I seek to record 4000, use `getPos` to remember that location, do other things and then use `setPos` to return to that record. It does not provide a mechanism for seeking randomly within a data set.